# javascript vbscript convert from rtf to html

Tags: javascript, vbscript, rtf

Does anyone know of any vbscript / javascript implementations of a RTF to HTML converter?

I have seen some in VB / c#, but cannot find any reference to a scripted version.  Before I start to write one - does anyone know of an existing open source project that deals with this?

Many thanks,

Franko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How comfortable are you with PHP? This class seems to do the trick, so you could either use it as is, or convert to Javascript, or even use as a guideline.

http://pastebin.ca/1688799

Comment: Thank you - perfect place for me to start,  much appreciated Gausie!

Comment: Could you post a link that would not expire?

Comment: -1 Link is dead. This is why I hate it when people post links without explanations.

Comment: Whatever I posted will be incredibly similar to this: http://freecode.com/projects/rtf2htm

Answer (score 2):

Frank -

You didn't specify which platform you are targeting.  However, the fact you mentioned VBScript as well as Javascript suggests you are at the least using a Windows-based machine.  If so, and you have access to a version of Word, you could use a script automating a conversion, using Word as an out of process server.  Even then, you didn't really say whether this is meant to be done from a Windows session, or via a web server.

If you wanted to do this from a Windows session, you could use the following VBScript, run by the Windows Scripting Host:

**[Rtf2Html.vbs]**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ConvertToHtml(documentFileName)
Const wdFormatHTML = 8
Dim fso
Dim wordApplication
Dim newDocument
Dim htmlFileName

    On Error Resume Next

    Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    documentFileName = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(documentFileName)

    If Not fso.FileExists(documentFileName) Then
        WScript.Echo "The file '" & documentFileName & "' does not exist."
        WScript.Quit
    End If

    Set wordApplication = WScript.CreateObject("Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Select Case Err.Number
        Case &H80020009
            WScript.Echo "Word not installed properly."
        Case Else
            ShowDefaultErrorMsg
        End Select
        wordApplication.Quit
        WScript.Quit
    End If

    Set newDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(documentFileName, False)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Select Case Err.Number
        Case Else
            ShowDefaultErrorMsg
        End Select
        wordApplication.Quit
        WScript.Quit
    End If

    ' Construct a file name which is the same as the original file, but with a different extension.
    htmlFileName = Left(documentFileName, InStrRev(documentFileName, ".")) & "htm"

    newDocument.SaveAs htmlFileName, wdFormatHTML

    newDocument.Close

    wordApplication.Quit

End Sub

Private Sub Main
Dim arguments

    Set arguments = WScript.Arguments

    If arguments.Count = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "Missing file argument."
    Else
        ConvertToHtml arguments(0)
    End If

End Sub
bad 
Private Sub ShowDefaultErrorMsg
    WScript.Echo "Error #" & CStr(Err.Number) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Err.Description
End Sub

Main
```

If you want to use this from a webserver, things are a little different.  You could adapt the VBScript for an ASP page, or convert it to an ASP.NET page.  In any case, you will have to replace the WSH objects with the appropriate internal objects.  However, be warned: whilst it is possible to use an out of process server from IIS, it is generally a bad idea, unless you know this is going to be an extremely low volume server.  Even then, the fact that Word potentially uses GUI elements makes this potentially dangerous, because it is possible that Word might show a dialogue in some error condition.

In this case, it may be better to disconnect the two processes by shelling out from the server script to the Windows scripting host code, and instead return a page that does a client side pull after an appropriate delay.

Comment: Hi Mark,

Amazingly thorough and helpful answer!  I should have specified I need to do this just in script - but smashing response!

Comment: "just in script" = without depending on external objects